# Why `ProgramTestContext::set_account` with a program account caches the first call?

Tags: solana-program, solana-program-test

`ProgramTestContext::set_account` caches the first call for a program account, not allowing it to the updated again. I tried updating a program account in 3 ways:

- by using a simple account with program data and `bpf_loader::id()` owner.
- by using two accounts: `UpgradeableLoaderState::Program` and `UpgradeableLoaderState::ProgramData` and updating the first one.
- by using two accounts: `UpgradeableLoaderState::Program` and `UpgradeableLoaderState::ProgramData` and updating the second one.

None of these options worked. Does anyone know how to do this? My trials can be consulted [here](https://github.com/andreisilviudragnea/example-helloworld/blob/program-test-set-account-bug/src/program-rust/src/lib.rs).

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you should be able to update the second one to update the program account.

As you noticed, there is some caching involved. The program cache, even in test environments, lasts at least 1 slot, so you cannot redeploy a program in the same slot twice.

To get around this, you should be able to warp the bank forward by one slot, by using `ProgramTestContext::warp_to_slot`, and then trying to use the program again.